# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Уважаемые филологи! Помогите!
Нужна ли запятая?
Выполненный грамотно, гостевой блогинг станет для тебя...

Answer (score 4):

Хорошо бы знать все предложение. Если причастный оборот имеет дополнительное значение причины (гостевой блогинг станет для тебя...по какой причине? так как выполнен грамотно), то запятая нужна.

А вот все-таки блогинг или блоггинг? -Здешнему редактору не нравится удвоенная согласная. Яндексу не нравится одинарная.В словарях нет.

Comment: "Блогинг", по Лопатину. Он вообще противник удвоения согласных в одном и том же корне, поэтому блог-блогер-блогинг.

Comment: Спасибо...

Comment: Ларf, здесь есть значение причины. Иначе зачем бы вообще упоминание, да еще в инверсном порядке: не "грамотно выполненный", а "выполненный грамотно"? Тту даже интонационная запятая была бы возможна помимо причины.